# problem with connecting to 1nce simcard through openvpn

Tags: connection, ip, openvpn

I am trying to acces my Dragino gateways remotely in order to make some changes to the configuration of those devices. They are connected to the network with 1nce SIM cards and have a up and running connection. I have set up a vpn connection so that I (hopefully) am on the same network as the SIM-cards. But I can't figure out how to connect to the devices.

I've tried every manual of the 1nce developerhub but I cannot figure out how to do it. I've also contacted the 1nce support team but they are slow to react.
When I try to ping a Simcard I've put into my phone it does respond and vice versa.
But i just dont get how to get it working with the draginos.